# how to get facebook page likes user data by week

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I have create one page, i have get data of page like user.
i have get result value only 3 by day but when i pass week and day_28 it's get result to me blank data , but in graph api show me pagination but i not need this , show all data one week . please can tell me what is problem how can i get this result by week.  this is my graph api 519285998271320/insights/page_fan_adds_unique/day

```
   {
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "page_fan_adds_unique",
      "period": "day",
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 0,
          "end_time": "2016-07-24T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
          "value": 0,
          "end_time": "2016-07-25T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
          "value": 0,
          "end_time": "2016-07-26T07:00:00+0000"
        }
      ],
      "title": "Daily New Likes",
      "description": "Daily: The number of new people who have liked your Page (Unique Users)",
      "id": "519285998271320/insights/page_fan_adds_unique/day"
    }
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to pass the value since and until in unixtime in this way.

```
519285998271320/insights?pretty=0&metric=page_fan_adds_unique&period=week&since=1493596800&until=1500534000
```

and the max period value is 3 months.